# What are the chances of throwing the same number die as someone else 4 times in a row?

Tags: probability

My son and I had one die each. We both rolled the same number 4 times in a row:- 1 6 3 2 
What are the chances of that happening?

Comment: I think the answer is $(\frac 16)^8 = \frac{1}{1679616}$ which is very close to $0$. Did it actually happen?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan you have the square of actual result.  The one person's role "doesn't count"  It is all on the second person to match the role that came of for the first roll of each round $\frac {1}{6^4} = \frac {1}{1296}$ which while uncommon, is not impossible.  Besides if you look at all opportunities for something rare to happen in a day, you do six impossible things before breakfast.

Comment: You don't need to repost. I read what you said and am frankly surprised that it actually happened (ofcourse each outcome has the exact same probability of occurring but still, you know).

Comment: @DougM I see what you mean :)

Comment: My son threw first each time. And each time I matched his number.

Answer (score 2):

The chances of both of you throwing $1,6,3,2$, in this order are $6^{-8}$. The chances of the two of you throwing the same numbers (not necessarily *those four*) $4$ times in a row are $6^{-4}$.

Comment: Yes it actually happened. We were starting a game of trivial pursuit. Highest throw goes first but we threw the same numbers 4 times in a row.

Comment: My son threw first each time. And each time I matched his number.

Comment: @JayClark If you're answering to user Mohammad Zuhair Khan, please do it in the comments to your OP, not in the ones to the answer (you are telling *me* and not *him*).